# What's the most efficient/practical way to create square extrusions when working in subd?

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

Below is an example of what I'm talking about.

My constraints are as follows:

- My mesh is using the subdivision surface modifier.
- I have to use support loops rather than edge creases.
- I have to reduce the amount of polygons in the mesh.
- There is an existing square face, and I want to extrude within that area without changing the topology outside of that area.

So my question is:

1. What does the ideal topology look like in this situation, assuming those constraints?
2. What's the most efficient way to create it, starting with a square face? Are there any addons that can help?

[image: example]

Edit: Here's an an example solution.
[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this kind of topology:

[image]

Same thing:

[image]

How I would go to create this topology?
First create a 3x3 grid:

[image]

Bevel what needs to be bevelled:

[image]

Create these edges and dissolve these others:

[image]

You should end up with this:

[image]

Comment: Can this solution be used if I only have one face that I must work within (as stated in the question)?

Comment: what do you mean by one face? Maybe show your wireframe if it helps to understand?

Comment: Added an extra image to the question.

Comment: If your solution works fine without pinching or artefacts, then I guess you can use it

Comment: I see, so IIUC typically you would just start within something like a 3x3 or 4x4 grid of faces, then inset from there, since that gives you the support loops for free.

Comment: I've edited my answer, this is the way I would do it but there may be others

Comment: Thanks for giving more info! Using bevel is great here for getting a consistent result.